# TransactionScope in multiple session factories

Tags: nhibernate, distributed-transactions

I need to perform distributed transactions in three databases.  To that end I inject three session factories in my service. I manage the transaction with the following code:

```
using(var ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, 
new TransactionOptions() { IsolationLevel = RepeatableRead }))
using(var session1 = _sessionFactory1.OpenSession())
using(var tran1 = session1.BeginTransaction()
using(var session2 = _sessionFactory2.OpenSession())
using(var tran2 = session2.BeginTransaction()
using(var session3 = _sessionFactory3.OpenSession())
using(var tran3 = session3.BeginTransaction()
{
     //Entity manipulation
     tran1.Commit();
     tran2.Commit();
     tran3.Commit();
     ts.Complete();
}
```

wich works well and dandy, the problem is that if I issue a return statement before the completion of the transaction, the second session factory gets to an inconsistent state, and in next invocations an exception is thrown when I try to open the session:

> Distributed transaction complete.  Either enlist this session in a new
>   transaction or the NULL transaction.

I need the nesting structure because I issue an indetermined number of commands in the entity manipulation part, each of them making changes in the three databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround to this problem is avoid the nesting of different sessions, if an object of a previously closed session is needed after, it can be declared out of the using of the origin session and passed to the following, the same can be done with any information neeeded from a previously closed session.

```
Client client;
using(var session1 = _sessionFactory1.OpenSession())
{
     ...
     client = session1.Get<Client>(myClientId);

     ...
}

using(var session2 = _sessionFactory2.OpenSession())
{   
     ...
     product = _session2.Load<Product>(myProductId);
     product.ClientId = client.Id;
     ...
}
```